# Following ForgeinKeys in Django's select_related to populate a *_set variable?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

I have some simple Django Models like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # some stuff

class Price(models.Model):
    event = models.ForgeinKey(Event)
```

i.e. each `Event` has 1 or more `Price`'s.

I am selecting some Events like this: `events = Event.objects.filter(…)`, and then looping over them `for event in events:`, inside the loop I need to access all the `Price` objects for each event (i.e. with `event.price_set`), however that does a new SQL query for each event. I have thousands of events, and this is causing thousands of queries. Is there some way I can prepopulate the `price_set` for each event all in one go?

I tried adding a `select_related` to the QuerySet, but it doesn't work (I can still see all the queries in the Django Debug Toolbar). Surely there's some way to do a join on the original SQL query which will bring in all the `Event`'s and their `Prices` in one query?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621082/select-related-backwards-relation-auto-model-population#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select/
It will allow you to get what you want with just 2 queries (1 for the events and 1 for the prices)

Answer (score 1):

As a hint to other people with this problem:

Django 1.4 (not yet released at the time of writing), has `prefetch_related` as a complement to `select_related`, which does exactly what I'm asking for here.